# Iteration in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, iteration

this is my code

```
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Logger"%>
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Level"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page isThreadSafe="false"%>
<%! int k = 0;%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Concurrency</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                out.print(k + "->" + i + "</br>");
                k++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
            }
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot understand why when I see the outcome on Tomcat ,i starts from 10.

my outcome

```
10->0
11->1
12->2
13->3
14->4
15->5
16->6
17->7
18->8
19->9
```

Does JSP follow some rules than Core Java rules?
I do not get it, why k waits till i reaches 10 and after that it starts printing?

Comment: Where is `k` being declared?

Comment: posted the whole code :)

Comment: How many times have you called this page? `<%!` is an instance variable.

Comment: i is starting from 0 only.. k is starting from 10

Comment: out.print(k + "->" + i + "</br>"); as per this line, k is printed first and i second so 10->0 means i=0

Comment: @BoristheSpider, if I am able to understand your question. The whole project is just a page which you see the code of it. :)

Comment: `<%!` is an instance variable, there is only a single instance of a JSP. This means that your `k` is shared across all page requests - it will be "persisted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%! int k = 0;%>` defines k as a field in the JSP's corresponding `Servlet`

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` defines i at the block level.

It will be natural for k to continue growing with each page request, as that will get mapped to the same `Servlet` class, reusing `k` but getting a newly initialized `i`.

---- In response for a request to explain in more detail ----

The JSP page isn't really ran as-is.  It is passed into a compiler and turned into a `.class` file.  Before it is passed into that compiler, it needs to be turned into a proper `.java` file, and the way this occurs is "roughly" as follows.

1. Wrap all the "text" with quotes to make them `String`s.
2. Unwrap all the "java blocks" to make them "code".
3. Pack it all up in something that inherits from `Servlet`.

Knowing where the "tag" fits into the "Servlet" can deepen your understanding of JSP.  I highly recommend you take a peek.

Depending on your Servlet Container, the compiler might be different, but many are callable in one form or fashion from the command line.  In many cases, this is done to "precompile" your JSPs, so look up precompiling JSPs for your environment to get a hint.

Often you will find command line options.  If you are lucky, sometimes those command line options include a "stop" at merely generationg the `.java` files (or an option to not remove the `.java` files after they are generated from the `.jsp` files.

Comment: your answer makes more sense, but would you please explain it more ?

Comment: how the page gets requested? does it request because of for loop?

Comment: Tomcat used to use `jasper` to compile JSPs, maybe they still do.  Also, `jspc` is the name of the compiler for some web servers (like Sun's).  Finally, if something is helpful, click the up arrow above the number, if it is misleading, click the down arrow below the number.

Comment: what arrow? I am using netbeans 8

Comment: You are also using a web browser to read this sentence.  To the right of every answer are arrows and a number.  Hoping that others click on these arrows is 95% of the reason that people bother to answer questions here at StackOverflow.

Comment: if you mean about voting your answer,I will as soon as I understand what is going on. Sorry to say I have difficulty to understand you. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is because `<%! int k = 0;%>` makes k stay around after execution.  Each time you run this page, the last value of k stays in memory.  You can either reset k lower down in a <% %> block, or remove the <%! %> block altogether from the code.

```
int k=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: does not k and i increment at the each iteration? why my java core program runs the way I want?

Comment: @Kick Buttowski, Because you didn't use `<%!` in your core Java program...you couldn't since that doesn't exist.

Comment: so in case keeping this <%! and filliping k and i, why it works then?

Comment: It just made it look like it did since the left hand started with 0 and only the right side was moving.

Comment: Budeveloperwjk t I do not get it, why k waits till i reaches 10 and after that it starts printing?